# Computing the Galois group of polynomials of high degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

I have the following polynomial $f(x)=x^6-15x^4-14x^3 + 75x^2-210x-76$ for which I know that $\sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt{5}$ is a root. I guessed $\sqrt[3]{7} - \sqrt{5}$ is also a root, and most probably the rest are complex. But I have no idea how to compute the Galois group of this polynomial. I know some methods for quartic, cubic and quadratic polynomials, but not for higher degree powers. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: if you have a field homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ into itself, what could it possibly map $\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt{5}$ to? You can deduce from this the decomposition field. Try to construct some intermediary fields.

Comment: with complex $\omega  $  so that  $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$   so that $ \omega^3 = 1,$  the roots are  $\sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $   $ \omega \, \sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $  $ \omega^2 \,\sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $  $\sqrt[3]{7} - \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $   $ \omega \, \sqrt[3]{7} - \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $  $ \omega^2 \,\sqrt[3]{7} - \sqrt{5} \; , \; \; \; \; $

Comment: Anyway, I got that by taking the companion matrix for $x^3 - 7$  and the companion matrix for $x^2 - 5$  and took the Kronecker sum, then confirmed that the characteristic polynomial matched your sextic